# low level animations in Swift

Tags: swift, animation, low-level

I have 50 polygons.
The properties of the polygons are on ‘pol’ array and their geometry is on ‘dat’.
For around 10 seconds all polygons undergo 2 color interpolations while at the same time they move across the screen.
Each polygon starts from a specific color and it interpolates to a new color for around 2 seconds.
2 seconds before the end each polygon interpolates to a 3rd color

This is Matlab code and I want to write it in swift.
I have no swift experience so I have to study about animations.
I am not expecting you to provide code.
I want to know if this is possible, especially the part where I am pausing the execution.
It will also help a lot if you can give me some references or even key words to search for it.
Thank you

```
% Array with the geometry of the polygons  
dat=zeros(10000,2);

% Array with the list of view updates
vlist=zeros(100,5);
% vlist(-,1)        Graphics handle of the polygon
% vlist(-,2)        Type of update, 1 geometry, 2 color
% vlist(-,3:5)      Properties of update, either entries on dat or rgb color 

% pol is an array with 50 rows and 18 columns
% There is a total of 50 polygons 
% pol(-,1)          Graphics handle of the polygon
% pol(-,2:3)        Coordinates of the polygon on dat array
% pol(-,4:5)        Motion animation, start and final step
% pol(-,6:7)        Color interpolation 1, start and final step
% pol(-,8:9)        Color interpolation 2, start and final step
% pol(-,10:12)      Start rgb color of interpolation 1
% pol(-,13:15)      Final rgb color of interpolation 1, also start of 2
% pol(-,16:18)      Final rgb color of interpolation 2

t_tot=10;               % Total time of the animation is seconds
fps=30;                 % Frames per second
dt=1/fps;               % Time step in seconds
s_final=t_tot * fps;    % Final step of the animation

for i=1:s_final
    % Counter of updates to the polygons, either geometry or color 
    iv=0;
    % Get the time at the start of the i step
    time1=tic;

    for j=1:50
        % Update the geometry of the j polygon
        if i>=pol(j,4) && i<=pol(j,5)
            % Do some geometry calculations, translations, 
            % rotations, enlargements

            % Add the geometry update to the update list 
            iv=iv+1;    vlist(iv,1:5)=[pol(j,1), 1, pol(j,2:3), 0]
        end

        % Update the color of the j polygon, interpolation 1
        if i>=pol(j,6) && i<=pol(j,7)
            % Use the current step to interpolate the color

            % Add the color update to the update list 
            iv=iv+1;    vlist(iv,1:5)=[pol(j,1), 2, color]
        end

        % Update the color of the j polygon, interpolation 2
        if i>=pol(j,8) && i<=pol(j,9)
            % Use the current step to interpolate the color

            % Add the color update to the update list 
            iv=iv+1;    vlist(iv,1:5)=[pol(j,1), 2, color]
        end
    end

    % Sent all updates to the view function
    updateview(iv, vlist, dat)

    % Get the time at the end of the i step
    time2=toc;
    
    % Calculate the remaining amount of time and pause execution
    twait=dt-(time2-time1)
    pause(twait)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately Apple provides plug-and-play solutions for managing 2D and even 3D graphics. I guess your new friend could be "SpriteKit", where 2D things like moving sprites, making particle effects, resizing and moving animations are the basic parts. It already contains a lot of optimization in the background for the iOS / iPadOS devices.

The 3D version of Apple's solution is SceneKit.

You can also get a "low level" access to the GPU by using Metal.

https://developer.apple.com/spritekit/

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/

https://developer.apple.com/metal/

You can also check out some third party libraries but I think these are the way to go on iOS / iPadOS. (besides of Unity, Unreal, etc.. engines)